# Iterators or lazy evaluation benefits

Tags: iterator, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I recently built a linq alternative in typescript for my clientside javascript. I know there are many open source items available but I wanted to build it myself for the challenge.
I started to look into lazy evaluation (iterators) my methods. I'm starting to struggle with the benefits.

If I have something like this.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

current eager evaluation

```
var myResult = myArray.Where(function(x){ x >= 4 });

//my result will be 4,5 - then I can run a Last
var myLastItem = myResult.Last();
```

my last item = 5.

If I combine them, I could do the following. The last method would only loop through 4,5 (filtered from the where)
So it wouldn't need to loop through the entire record set (myArray)

```
var myLastItem = myArray.Where(function(x){ x >= 4 }).Last();
```

if we try to lazy evaluate this with iterators how would this help at all?

The only benefit is if we had an if statement where we might need the result - or may not. This way the linq statements are never ran.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eager evaluation/applicative order and lazy evaluation/normal order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634542/eager-evaluation-applicative-order-and-lazy-evaluation-normal-order)